# React hook is fired on every key press, supposed to only fire with onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, formik

I've written a hook for a Formik form I'm creating so that on a specific field, whenever a Selection option is selected, I want the hook to be called.

But what is happening, is that in every form field, on every key press, my hook is being called. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but would love any pointers on what I can do to only call the hook on the select change.

**Here's my `displayProvinces.js` hook**

```js
import React from 'react';
import GetDistrictsAPI from '@/utils/services/GetDistrictsAPI';
import GetProvincesAPI from '@/utils/services/GetProvincesAPI';
import {Field, useFormikContext } from 'formik';

export default function DisplayProvinces(){
  
  const [ provinces ] = GetProvincesAPI();
  const handleSelectedProvince = useProvinces();
  
  function useProvinces(){
    console.log('Fired')
    function handleSelectedProvince(pr) {
      console.log('Selected Province = ' +pr)
      let districts = GetDistrictsAPI(pr);
    }
    
    return handleSelectedProvince;
  }
  
  const {setFieldValue} = useFormikContext();
  
  return (
    <Field
      as="select"
      id="pxProvince"
      name="pxProvince"
      onChange={(e)=> {
        handleSelectedProvince(e.target.value)
        setFieldValue('pxProvince', e.target.value)
      }}
      className="mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md"
    >
      {!provinces ? provinces : provinces.map((p, i) => (
        <option key={i} value={p.prov_id}>{p.prov_name}</option>
      ))}
    </Field>
  )
}
```

In this code snippet, I can see 'Fired' in the console, for every key press, even though it is only supposed to be called from the associated select `onChange` event.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

And this is how I'm calling the component

```html
<div className="col-span-6 sm:col-span-6 lg:col-span-2">
 <CVLabel field="forms.rego.fields.px.province" required='1' />
 <DisplayProvinces />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every onChange event, you're setting up the state(setFieldValue) which triggers react to re-evaluate and re-render the component, As the re-evaluation happens react again execute useProvinces() method which logs "Fired" in the console, and returns handleSelectedProvince reference.

There're two ways to solve your problem, either use useMemo() hooks which memo-ized the value returned by the passed function and recalculate the value when any dependency changes.

Or you can tweak in the code  like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import GetDistrictsAPI from '@/utils/services/GetDistrictsAPI';
import GetProvincesAPI from '@/utils/services/GetProvincesAPI';
import {Field, useFormikContext } from 'formik';

export default function DisplayProvinces(){
  
  const [ provinces ] = GetProvincesAPI();
  function handleSelectedProvince(pr) {
    console.log("Fired!!")
    console.log('Selected Province = ' +pr)
    let districts = GetDistrictsAPI(pr);
  }
  
  const {setFieldValue} = useFormikContext();
  
  return (
    <Field
      as="select"
      id="pxProvince"
      name="pxProvince"
      onChange={(e)=> {
        handleSelectedProvince(e.target.value)
        setFieldValue('pxProvince', e.target.value)
      }}
      className="mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md"
    >
      {!provinces ? provinces : provinces.map((p, i) => (
        <option key={i} value={p.prov_id}>{p.prov_name}</option>
      ))}
    </Field>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @anuurag-tripathi! When I was looking at your code, I was seeing that I was over complicating it and kept it more simple. Sometimes just need a second pair of eyes! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it happens because the re-rendering occurs. Every time your `DisplayProvinces` component re-render, it will call the `useProvinces()` function which will log `Fired`. Try to use `useMemo` hook to prevent your function getting re-initialized every component renders.

```
const handleSelectedProvince = useMemo(() => useProvinces(), []);
```

It will save the results of the `useProvinces` (which is a `handleSelectedProvince` function) even the component re-renders. More info about `useMemo` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Comment: Thanks for this, looks like it is helping and I only see it firing once now, as expected. 
But my eslint is now complaining, even though the code executes fine
`ESLint: React Hook "useProvinces" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.(react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)`

I'll do some more reading on the link they provide

Comment: About the error: Every react hook should be used inside the functional component and Don't call them inside a nested function, loops, and conditions. You can read more about it here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html